# Batch command after loop is not executed

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

I have the following batch file:

```
:RELEASE
for /d %%i in (D:\Projekte\UDG\OSB-Projekte\*) do (
::cd "%%i" & mvn versions:use-latest-versions -Dincludes=de.db.udg.test-framework:component-tester & mvn clean test >> %back%/test.log
)
goto MAKEDECISION
:MAKEDECISION
set /p decision=Do you want to commit?[[c]ommit/[r]evert/[e]xit]
```

however the cmd immediately closes after the loop.

Comment: Maybe because `::cd` with the two colons comments out the logic within the loop? Omit the colons from that line and rerun it. Otherwise you might want to put `CALL :MAKEDECISION` inside the loop in place of the commented out `::cd~` commands? Put `GOTO :EOF` or `PAUSE` after the loop closing `)` on the line beneath it too and see if either of those help.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT i commented it out, so the testruns were faster, even without the double colons the goto wasn't called, neither PAUSE. :/
according to my logic i have to call MAKEDECISION **after** the loop

Comment: I'm glad to help give you the pointer on using `CALL` to call a subroutine within a loop as I've used with success in the past. Consider editing your answer to give more detail explaining why this works to make it more helpful for others that may come along and see your post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to use the `call` command for `mvn` -> `cd "%%i" & call mvn versions:use-latest-versions -Dincludes=de.db.udg.test-framework:component-tester & call mvn clean test >> %back%/test.log`

Answer (score 2):

This example is using the `mvn` command. This is not really an executable program, it is actually another batch file named `mvn.bat` (you can probably search for it in your system's `%PATH%`).

Whether inside the `for` loop, or outside the loop, the problem will be the same: by referencing a batch file, control is turned over to that batch file, and the current one will stop.

As [0x45](https://superuser.com/users/887804/0x45) has noted [in their own answer](https://superuser.com/a/1308051/243707), using `call` will run the sub-command, and then return control to the parent process, as expected.